# Ruby CSV Conversion Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, scripting, type-conversion

I am simply trying to get the average two columns of a colon separated file. What am I doing wrong here?

```
/experimental/1$ cat list.csv
a:7:98:East
b:2:34:East
c:10:94:North
d:7:43:West
e:6:88:South

/experimental/1$ cat play.rb 
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'
average_spending = Array.new
CSV.foreach('list.csv', converters: :numeric, { :col_sep => ':' }) do |row|
  average_spending << row[2] / row[1]
end

/experimental/1$ ./play.rb
./play.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
... :numeric, { :col_sep => ':' }) do |row|
...                               ^
./play.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

Thank you in advance,

~Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CSV.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) accepts 2 arguments and block(you are trying to pass 3), use

```
CSV.foreach('list.csv', { converters: :numeric, col_sep: ':' }) {...}
```

Comment: An explanation of why they got a syntax error might be nice.